# php hook core functions

Tags: php, security, hook

I want to hook before execution / or replace standard core functions, for example I'm going to prevent both `include` and `require` access to any scripts. Is there any way to make it without any extra dll's? Or in another case `is_array($myarr);` I would hook at `array($myarr) === $myarr;` (*looks like it is faster*) to avoid creating extra classes and functions.

And how could I prevent all PHP executions after some moment? I have HTML templates with PHP parts `<?=$myvar?>` I want to prevent short syntax and execution at all when my script ends work, what do I have to try?

Comment: bool override_function (
         string $function_name , 
         string $function_args , 
         string $function_code )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About hooks to standart functions: there is no way to do that without external modules. [APD PECL module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.apd.php)
will do the job.

```
rename_function('require', 'internal_require'); // saving reference to original function
override_function('require', '$filename', 
                  'print "require called"; internal_require($filename);');
```

Second question is not very clear. Do you want to hook on standart `is_array` function, to `array()` lexical construct or `(array)` type casting?

About stopping php interpretation: have a look at [__halt_compiler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php) function. But keep in mind that succeeding blocks of php will be just embedded in HTML (thus visible to everybody).

Comment: Thanks, nice answer. About second - yes, i want to route standart func - to my which is faster. And about halt_compiler if it would be enought to regexp remove all inside php tags, to avoid visible?

Comment: @Jacob88 you can implement your `is_array` with the method I provided above. And as for removing everything inside php tags I strongly advise you to do it with any advanced text editor (or stream editor) than try to do that dynamically. Just use `Search and Replace` tool.

Comment: Should be noted that statements like `require` or `include` cannot be overridden

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable functions, you can use safe mode, but it is deprecated and not recommended. And as madfriend says, __halt_compiler just sends everything below it as text. Bear in mind that it can only be called from the outermost scope - I.e. not inside curly braces (if, loops, functions etc.)